# Test hover CSS properties using QUnit

Tags: jquery, css, qunit

I want to make a simple test using QUnit to check what the CSS properties of an element are when it's hovered.

Say I have a link with CSS defined as

```
a:hover {text-decoration: none}
```

I'm trying to have QUnit trigger the mouseover event and then check what the CSS of the link is, but it's not working. However, when I manually hover the link, the test gives the correct results.

Here's the QUnit code

```
QUnit.test('hover test', function() {
    $('a').mouseover(function (){
        QUnit.ok($('a').css('text-decoration') == 'none');
    });

    $('a').mouseover();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as it is not a trusted event.

> Events that are generated by the user agent, either as a result of
>   user interaction, or as a direct result of changes to the DOM, are
>   trusted by the user agent with privileges that are not afforded to
>   events generated by script through the
>   DocumentEvent.createEvent("Event") method, modified using the
>   Event.initEvent() method, or dispatched via the
>   EventTarget.dispatchEvent() method. The isTrusted attribute of trusted
>   events has a value of true, while untrusted events have a isTrusted
>   attribute value of false.
>
> Most untrusted events should not trigger default actions, with the
>   exception of click or DOMActivate events.

What you can do however is created a new class based on your :hover styling and then toggle that class on mouseover/mouseleave.

Comment: I have no control of what the end CSS is but I need to test that it does what I expect it to do so this solution is not applicable in my case. However, this does answer my question, thanks!